# Как повернуть таблицу (Pivot)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, c#

Есть таблица успеваемости. Поля:

```
ZachetkaId,SemesterId,DisciplinaId,Ocenka
```

мне надо перевернуть таблицу, чтоб строками были zachetka (потом перетяну через join Фио),а столбцами дисциплины. Дело в том, что подобный код делает это, но надо заранее знать, с какими дисциплинами работать, а мне нужен универсальный запрос, где б я явно не указывал дисциплины

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT zachetka,disciplina,ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki
  WHERE disciplina IN('29','32','35','42')
) AS pr
PIVOT (
  max(ocenka) FOR disciplina IN([29],[32],[35],[42])
) AS pvt
```

потом заменяю на

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT zachetka,disciplina,ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki
  WHERE disciplina IN(**select distinct disciplina from disciplini**)
) AS pr
PIVOT (
  max(ocenka) FOR disciplina IN([29],[32],[35],[42])
) AS pvt
```

А мне надо ещё и в запросе pivot тоже самое, но вставить такой же запрос не получается...

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Код форматируется кнопкой 101010 в редакторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, если кому интересно...

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName([nazvaniedisciplini])
                        FROM disciplini  FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')

SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT s.Fio, ocenka,nazvaniedisciplini
       FROM uspevaemostocenki as Uo inner join students as S on uo.zachetka=s.zachetka inner join Disciplini as D on d.Disciplina=uo.disciplina) base
       PIVOT (SUM(ocenka) FOR [nazvaniedisciplini]
       IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```