# Поворот таблицы

Tags: oracle, база-данных, sql, sql-server, mysql

Делал подобный пример: [Как повернуть таблицу (Pivot)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73294)

```
Есть таблица Успеваемости,Студентов,Дисциплин

Табл Успеваемость
-Zachetka
-Disciplina
-Yearname ------(Семестр)
-Ocenka ------*(Не интеджер!, т.к. ещё возм зачёты,задолжности и т.д. и делать ещё табл,что б там был номер и в др. табл расшифровка значения не стал....хотя...может и лучше)*
```

Я хочу что б можно было перевернуть таблицу из этого вида в вид (напр.)

```
           МАТЕМАТИКА    фИЗИКА
Иванов И.И.    5           ЗАЧЁТ
Петров П.П.    2           нет зачёта
```

До этого с Piviot-ом делал, но в нём надо указывать функцию сум ,макс или подобное, а здесь не нужны функции,нужно просто взять нужное значение и в итоге вывести не интеджер значение (например - задолженность) и это не катит (ну или я не знаю).

Вот код, который решает данную проблему, но но заранее надо знать, какие дисциплины нужны.

В предыдущем примере получает значения дисциплин ещё 1 запрос и формирует строку, здесь я не могу так сделать.

```
SELECT S.fio, USP.zachetka,


Disciplina45= ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina = 45 AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka and yearname='1'),0),


Disciplina32= ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina = 32 AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka and yearname='1'),0),



Disciplina41= ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina = 41 AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka and yearname='1'),0),


Disciplina42= ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina = 42 AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka and yearname='1'),0)

 FROM Uspevaemostocenki as USP inner join Students as S on s.zachetka=USP.zachetka where yearname='1'
```

В этом примере я явно указываю, что хочу выбрать дисциплины. А как мне узнать список дисциплин, например, в этом семестре и впихнуть их номера (и join-ом вытащить названия этих дисциплин), что б получилось всё то же, что написал в коде, но заранее не указывая дисциплины?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/42644/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82-%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: А как создать курсор, чтоб он брал значения "Назв_дисциплины","Код_дисциплины", и вставлял
[Назв_дисциплины]= ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina = 45 AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka and yearname='[Код_дисциплины]'),0),
и повторял этот запрос столько раз,сколько дисциплин в списке(select nazvaniedisciplini,disciplina from [таблица1] where [какоето условие])
а потом вставлял это в главный запрос...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE  @disciplina   VARCHAR(1000),
         @nazvaniedisciplini     VARCHAR(50),
         @message VARCHAR(max),
         @mymessage VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE diciplini_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT disciplina,nazvaniedisciplini
    FROM disciplini
set @message='select S.fio, USP.zachetka, '
OPEN diciplini_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM diciplini_cursor INTO @disciplina , @nazvaniedisciplini
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SELECT @message= @message +@nazvaniedisciplini+' =ISNULL((SELECT ocenka FROM uspevaemostocenki WHERE disciplina ='+
                    + @disciplina+' AND zachetka =  USP.zachetka ),0),',
    @mymessage=@message
    --PRINT @message

    FETCH NEXT FROM diciplini_cursor 
      INTO @disciplina , @nazvaniedisciplini
END
set @mymessage = LEFT(@message, LEN(@message) - 1) 
set @mymessage=cast(@mymessage+' FROM Uspevaemostocenki as USP inner join Students as S on s.zachetka=USP.zachetka' as varchar(max))
print @mymessage
execute(@mymessage)
CLOSE diciplini_cursor
DEALLOCATE diciplini_cursor
```